# How do I Determine The Number Of Days In A Month from a particular date in angularjs 2?

Tags: date, typescript

I am using angularjs 2 and type script.
I want the number of days in a month from a particular date given by user.
How do I Determine that?
Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this angular2 javascript, TypeScript or DART?

Comment: i'm using TypeScript. i have  this.todayDate = new Date(); now i want no of days of the month in that particular date.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bit late, but the right answer is a follows:

In order to find the number of days in a month, you need to get the 'date' of the 0<sup>th</sup> day of the *next* month:

`let daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();`